# Execute equation from the elements of a list and multiple multiindex dataframes in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the following list and dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([("K", "A1", "A"), 
                                  ("K", "B1", "B"), 
                                  ("K", "C1", "C"),
                                  ("M", "A1", "A"), 
                                  ("M", "B1", "B"), 
                                  ("M", "C1", "C")])

data = [[5, 10, 40, 4, 8, 9], [2, 15, 70, 1, 7, 3], [6, 14, 60, 12, 41, 61]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)
lst = [5, '*', 'A1.A', '+', 'C1.C']
```

The way the column multiindex names are listed in the list can change if it can help.

I would like to create a code to execute the equation in the lst like `5 x df['A1','A'] + df['C1','C']` but for all the column combination that match second and third level, returning the following result:

```
df[("K", "N1", "N")] = 5 * df[("K", "A1", "A")] + df[("K", "C1", "C")]
df[("M", "N1", "N")] = 5 * df[("M", "A1", "A")] + df[("M", "C1", "C")]
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.eval.html) with a loop on the first column level unique keys:

```
df_name = 'df'

for key in df.columns.get_level_values(0).unique():
    query = ''.join([f'{df_name}.{key}.{x}' if (isinstance(x, str) and '.' in x)
                     else str(x)
                     for x in lst])
    df[(key, 'N1', 'N')] = pd.eval(query)

df = df.sort_index(axis=1, level=0, sort_remaining=False)

print(df)
```

Of course, if you don't need to build it from the list, you can simplify to:

```
for key in df.columns.get_level_values(0).unique():
     df[(key, 'N1', 'N')] = 5 * df[(key, "A1", "A")] + df[(key, "C1", "C")]
```

Output:

```
   K               M             
  A1  B1  C1  N1  A1  B1  C1   N1
   A   B   C   N   A   B   C    N
0  5  10  40  65   4   8   9   29
1  2  15  70  80   1   7   3    8
2  6  14  60  90  12  41  61  121
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid a for loop but still, this solution is good.

Comment: May I ask why you have this input based on a list with operators as strings?

Comment: I want to translate a formula written in excel to an equation in python: for example ```a*[Outdoor, Hours] - [Outdoor, free]``` which will be written in Excel to be read by the code in Python and do the calculation for all the first level multiindex columns such as ```df[Today, Outdoor, Hours]``` but also ```df[Yesterday, Outdoor, Hours]``` etc

Comment: Do you know how I can get the ```query = ''.join([f'{df_name}.{key}.{mfuction(x)['a']}' if (isinstance(x, str) and '.' in x)```. I am essentially adding the ```mfuction(x)['a']``` which is a fuction and returns a dictionary but it returns an error.